# limit in the geolocation of multiple points in google fusion tables

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, kml, google-fusion-tables, limits

I'm trying to geolocate these 27 points at the same time, in the same row. But the process returns only the first 10 points, even if in the preview they are all 27 correctly geolocated. Why? Is there a particular limit to the number of points I can locate?

```
<Point><coordinates>7.680237,45.064504,0.0</coordinates></Point>
<Point><coordinates>7.681675,45.061957,0.0</coordinates></Point>
<Point><coordinates>7.685044,45.060768,0.0</coordinates></Point>
<Point><coordinates>7.686482,45.06029,0.0</coordinates></Point>
<Point><coordinates>7.689443,45.05926,0.0</coordinates></Point>
<Point><coordinates>7.692157,45.060836,0.0</coordinates></Point>
<Point><coordinates>7.693799,45.062837,0.0</coordinates></Point>
<Point><coordinates>7.69352,45.06605,0.0</coordinates></Point>
<Point><coordinates>7.693316,45.065519,0.0</coordinates></Point>
<Point><coordinates>7.693723,45.065193,0.0</coordinates></Point>
<Point><coordinates>7.694796,45.069065,0.0</coordinates></Point>
<Point><coordinates>7.689893,45.072081,0.0</coordinates></Point>
<Point><coordinates>7.684025,45.075225,0.0</coordinates></Point>
<Point><coordinates>7.682716,45.075377,0.0</coordinates></Point>
<Point><coordinates>7.675881,45.078135,0.0</coordinates></Point>
<Point><coordinates>7.674809,45.076672,0.0</coordinates></Point>
<Point><coordinates>7.673264,45.074521,0.0</coordinates></Point>
<Point><coordinates>7.672727,45.073809,0.0</coordinates></Point>
<Point><coordinates>7.671729,45.072399,0.0</coordinates></Point>
<Point><coordinates>7.670302,45.071013,0.0</coordinates></Point>
<Point><coordinates>7.669648,45.070119,0.0</coordinates></Point>
<Point><coordinates>7.669197,45.068565,0.0</coordinates></Point>
<Point><coordinates>7.670592,45.06802,0.0</coordinates></Point>
<Point><coordinates>7.672427,45.067414,0.0</coordinates></Point>
<Point><coordinates>7.67557,45.065981,0.0</coordinates></Point>
<Point><coordinates>7.675592,45.06633,0.0</coordinates></Point>
<Point><coordinates>7.675892,45.064094,0.0</coordinates></Point>
```

Answer (score 1):

The Google Maps reverse geocoder (whichever one you are using) is subject to a quota and a rate limit.  If you don't check for and handle the status OVER_QUERY_LIMIT returned, you will get that behavior.

There used to be a limitation on multigeometries that only the 10 most prominent locations would show (can't find that in the documentation for FusionTables anymore though).  Put each point in its own row.